# perl number of lines in a string

Tags: string, perl

Using `perl`, is there any single command which give me the number of lines inside a string?

```
my $linenum= .... $str ....
```

It should work for when the string is empty, single line, and multiple lines.

Comment: The two perl functions that you want to look into are `split()` that splits a string into a list and `scalar()` that when given a list returns the length of the list.

Comment: @DovGrobgeld do you  mean `scalar(split($str))`? it didnt work

Comment: Check the documentation for `split()`, e.g. by `perldoc -f split`. `split()` takes two parameters. The first is a pattern (which can be a string) used for splitting, and the string to split. E.g. `split('\n',$str)'.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Try to use a regular expression

Comment: I am new in perl. any suggested regex?

Comment: my $count = () = $str =~ /\n/g;

Answer (score 13):

You can count number of newline chars `\n` in the string (or `\r` for Mac newline)

```
my $linenum = $str =~ tr/\n//;
```

Comment: You should add `$number_of_lines ++;` to add 1 to the result because counting only the new line character `\n` skips the last line.

Comment: That depends on whether last line is terminated by `\n`. `$linenum++ if $str !~ /\n\z/`

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted @rplantiko's answer into a full subroutine that works the way I picture it, with handling for undef and "".  It also knows about how the last line of text can be missing a "\n" and returns the apparent line count ( which is the count of "\n" +1 )

```
# should work on windows + unix but not the old mac
sub count_lines_in_string { 
    $_ = shift;
    return 0 if( !defined $_ or $_ eq "");
    my $lastchar = substr $_, -1,1;
    my $numlines = () = /\n/g;
# was last line a whole line with a "\n"?;
    return $numlines + ($lastchar ne "\n"); 
}
say count_lines_in_string("asdf\nasdf\n") ;
say count_lines_in_string undef;
say count_lines_in_string "a";
```